# Reactjs with 3x.antd --- Warning: `getFieldDecorator` will override `value`, so please don't set `value` directly and use `setFieldsValue` to set it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, antd, react-functional-component

I am facing some problems **Warning: `getFieldDecorator` will override `value`, so please don't set `value` directly and use `setFieldsValue` to set it.**
Please help me...

```
{initialJobPropertiesApps && initialJobPropertiesApps.map((types: any, i: number): React.ReactNode => (
                  <tr data-row-key={`index-${types.id + i}` + 1}>
                    <td style={{width:'40%'}}>{types.name}<br />
                      <h6>{types.details}</h6>
                    </td>
                    <td style={{width:'10%'}}>{types.default === "" ? "(blank)" : types.default}</td>
                    <td style={{width:'50%'}}>

  {types.type === "boolean" ?
    <Form.Item label="">{getFieldDecorator(
      `${types.id}`, (formConfig.AppsRadios, {
        initialValue: types.value,
      }))(
        <Radio.Group
          //onChange={onAppsRadio}
          name={'appsRadio'}
        >
          <Radio value="0">No </Radio>
          <Radio value="1">Yes</Radio>
          <Radio value="">User Account Setting</Radio>
        </Radio.Group>)}
    </Form.Item>

    : types.type === "number" ?
      <Form.Item label="">{getFieldDecorator(
        `${types.id}`, (formConfig.AppsRadioss, {
          initialValue: types.value,
        }))(<Input type="text"
          //onChange={onNumberChange}
        />)}
      </Form.Item>
      : types.pname === "JOB_TABLE" ? 
      <Form.Item label="">{getFieldDecorator(
        `${types.id}`, (formConfig.JobTable, {
          initialValue: types.activeTable,
        }))(<Select
          onChange={onJobTableChange}                                         
          style={{ minWidth: 200, maxWidth: 200 }}                     
        >
        {types.tables && types.tables.map((jobTable: { value: React.Key | undefined; label: boolean | React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal | null | undefined; })  => {
            return (
              <Option value={jobTable.value} key={jobTable.value}>
                {jobTable.label}
              </Option >
            );
          }
        )}
        </Select>)}
      </Form.Item>
      
      : types.pname === "CHANGE_CURRENCY" ?
        <><Form.Item label="" style={{paddingBottom:'0px', marginBottom:'0px'}}>
          {getFieldDecorator(
          `${types.id}`, (formConfig.AppsCheckboxINR, {
            initialValue: types.value === "No conversion" ? '' : types.value,
          }))(<Input
            type="text"
            name={'noconversion'}
            disabled={conversion}
            style={{paddingBottom:'0px', marginBottom:'0px'}}
          />)}                               
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>
            {getFieldDecorator('noconversion', {
              initialValue: initialChecked,
            })(<Checkbox onChange={onChangeINR} defaultChecked={initialChecked}>No conversion</Checkbox>)}
            {getFieldDecorator(
            'id_curr_val', (formConfig.IdCurrVal,{
              initialValue: types.id,
            }))( 
              <Input type="hidden"  /> )}
            </Form.Item>
           </>

        : types.pname === "email" ?
        <>
        <Form.Item label="">{getFieldDecorator(
          `${types.id}`, (formConfig.Changevalue, {
            initialValue: types.value,
          }))(<Input type="text"/>)}
        </Form.Item></> 
        : <Form.Item label="">{getFieldDecorator(
          `${types.id}`, (formConfig.ChangevalueOther, {
            initialValue: types.value,
          }))(<Input type="text"/>)}
        </Form.Item>}

  <Form.Item label="" className={styles.hiddenFilds}>
    {getFieldDecorator(
      `pname_${types.id}`, (formConfig.Pnames, {
        initialValue: types.pname,
      }))(
        <Input type="hidden" value={types.pname} />
      )}
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item label="" className={styles.hiddenFilds}>
    {getFieldDecorator(
      `pval_${types.id}`, (formConfig.Pvals, {
        initialValue: types.pval,
      }))(
        <Input type="hidden" value={types.pval} />
      )}
  </Form.Item>
</td>
```

))}

Comment: Any solution? I'm facing the same problem